# can Ignite Streamer.addData be executed on separate node from the StreamReceiver/Visitor?

Tags: ignite

Is it possible to do Stream injection from a Client Node and intercept the same stream in the Server Node to process the stream before inserting in the cache ?

The reason for doing this is that the Client Node receives the stream from an external source and the same needs to be injected into a partitioned cache based on AffinityKey across multiple server nodes. The stream needs to be intercepted on each node and processed with the lowest latency. 
I could've used cache events to do this but StreamVisitor is supposed to be faster.

following is the sample that i am trying to execute. Start 2 nodes : one containing the streamer, other containing the streamReciever :

public class StreamerNode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ......
        Ignition.setClientMode(false);
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(igniteConfiguration);

```
    CacheConfiguration<SeqKey, String> myCfg = new CacheConfiguration<SeqKey, String>("myCache");
    ......
    IgniteCache<SeqKey, String> myCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(myCfg);
    IgniteDataStreamer<SeqKey, String> myStreamer = ignite.dataStreamer(myCache.getName()); // Create Ignite Streamer for windowing data

    for (int i = 51; i <= 100; i++) {
        String paddedString = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.leftPad(i+"", 7, "0") ;
        String word = "TEST_" + paddedString;
        SeqKey seqKey = new SeqKey("TEST", counter++ );
        myStreamer.addData(seqKey, word) ;
    }
}
```

}

public class VisitorNode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ......
        Ignition.setClientMode(false);
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(igniteConfiguration);

```
    CacheConfiguration<SeqKey, String> myCfg = new CacheConfiguration<SeqKey, String>("myCache");
    ......
    IgniteCache<SeqKey, String> myCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(myCfg);
    IgniteDataStreamer<SeqKey, String> myStreamer = ignite.dataStreamer(myCache.getName()); // Create Ignite Streamer for windowing data

    myStreamer.receiver(new StreamVisitor<SeqKey, String>() {
        int i=1 ;
        @Override
        public void apply(IgniteCache<SeqKey, String> cache, Map.Entry<SeqKey, String> e) {
            String tradeGetData = e.getValue();
            System.out.println(nodeID+" : visitorNode ..count="+ i++ + " received key="+e.getKey() + " : val="+ e.getValue());
            //do some processing here before inserting in the cache .. 
            cache.put(e.getKey(), tradeGetData);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can be executed on a different node. Usually, `addData()` is executed on client node, and `StreamReceiver` works on server node. You don't have to do anything special to make it happen.

As for the rest of your post, can you elaborate it with more details and samples perhaps? I could not understand the setup that is desired.

You can use continuous queries if you don't need to modify data, only act on it.

Comment: Thanks Alamar for your response. sorry for the delay in providing the details .